# Proving Logarithims

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I'm trying to figure out how to go about proving this statement:

$$n^{\log(a)} = a^{\log(n)}$$

I'm told that I cannot prove from both sides. I tried to $\log$ the first side to get:

$\log(n)\log(a)$

But I'm not sure where to go from here, any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you get if you take the log of the other side?

Comment: Thing is I can't do that, I can only work from one side. (Proove left side = Right Side)

Comment: Ok.  rewrite $log(n)log(a)$ as $log(a)log(n)$ and exponentiate.

Comment: I'm quite confused now, am I even allowed to log the first side? Doesn't that mean I would have to Log the second side as well, but my professor tells me I can only work from one side.

Comment: My (most recent) suggestion only works with one side.  We know that $xlog(y)=log(x^y)$ so $log(a)log(n) = log(n^{log(a)})$ and $log(n)log(a)=log(a^{log(n)})$.  But of course $log(a)log(n)=log(n)log(a)$.

Comment: Forgive me for trying to read your professor's mind, but I imagine what she means is that you cannot *start* with the assumption that $A=B$, manipulate both sides simultaneously, and then arrive at a true statement. However, it is perfectly fine to take the log of both sides, $\log(A)$ and $\log(B)$, *separately*, and then observe that they are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just do some simple manipulation to get the result. We can take a log and exponentiate the left side:

$$n^{\log(a)}=e^{\log(n^{\log(a)})}=e^{\log(a)\log(n)}=e^{\log(n)\log(a)}=e^{\log(a^{\log(n)})}=a^{\log(n)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can use it, but it is well known that

$$x^y = e^{(\ln x)y} $$

where $\ln$ is the natural logarithm and $e$ is Eulers constant. Just apply this.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, care to explain, I'm not familiar with this property?

Comment: Do you know that $y\ln x = \ln \left(x^y\right)$?

Comment: Since the exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$ and the natural logarithm are inverse it is $e^{\ln x} = x$. Further it is $(e^{\ln x})^y = e^{\ln y}$. These two are in every mathematical table. Knowing this you can use $x=n$ and $y=\ln a$. Then apply what I wrote, switch the order of the logarithms by commutativity and apply again what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n=a^x$, then $\log n=x\log a$ by taking logs.

Then, by substitution, $n^{\log a}=(a^x)^{\log a}=\dots$

---

How to find the method - well you start with $n$ to some power, and you want to end with $a$ to some power, so it is natural to express $n$ as a power of $a$, and once this is done the result drops out.

Comment: Note that the base of the logarithms is not given in your question and this method is independent of the base.